# Trying to add google maps in windows form

Tags: c#, google-maps, windows-forms-designer

I am currently working on adding google maps into windows forms but I keep getting the error in the image below.

```
string search = textBox1.Text;
StringBuilder querysearch = new StringBuilder();
querysearch.Append("https://www.google.com/maps/");
if (search != string.Empty)
{
querysearch.Append(search);
}
webBrowser1.Navigate(querysearch.ToString());
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

To disable this JavaScript error.

Comment: Glad that I helped you. I recommend you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed?view=netcore-3.1) link to enrich your knowledge.